# Navgation elements disappear when resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I put the browser on half screen (windows button + left or right) the top menu items are unreadable and also if I zoom in the top menu are not visible.
Please below html and Css code I guess which is having issue

```
<div><nav class="navbar-inverse" ng-class="::{'navbar':!isViewNative, 'is-native': isViewNative}"
   role="navigation">
<div ng-show="::!isViewNative" class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" ng-if="::!portal.logo" href="?id={{::portal.homepage_dv}}"><span>{{::portal.title}}</span></a>
  <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-logo" ng-if="::portal.logo" href="?id={{::portal.homepage_dv}}">
    <img ng-src="{{::portal.logo}}" />
  </a>

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sp-nav-bar">
    <span class="sr-only">${Toggle navigation}</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div sp-navbar-toggle="" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="sp-nav-bar">
  <!-- Include The Menu -->
  <sp-widget widget="data.menu"></sp-widget>
 <ul ng-if="::(!user.logged_in && page.id != portal.login_page_dv && !data.hasLogin)" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href ng-click="openLogin()">${Login}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="::user.logged_in" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <!-- chat, avatar, and logout -->
     <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="visible-lg-inline">${Useful Links}</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a ng-href="?id=ess_page_vtb">${Visual Task Boards}</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="?id=reports">${Reports}</a></li>
        <li><a href="/nav_to.do">${Support Portal}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="::data.connect_support_queue_id"><a href ng-click="openPopUp()">${Live Chat}</a></li>
     <li><sp-widget widget="data.languageSelector"></sp-widget></li>

    <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="navbar-avatar"><sn-avatar class="avatar-small-medium" primary="userID" /></span>
        <span class="visible-lg-inline">{{::user.name}}</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a ng-href="?id=user_profile&sys_id={{::user.sys_id}}">${Profile}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{::portal.logoutUrl}}">${Logout}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="visible-xs-block"><a ng-href="?id=user_profile&sys_id={{::user.sys_id}}"><span class="navbar-avatar"><sn-avatar class="avatar-small-medium" primary="userID" /></span>{{::user.name}}</a></li>
    <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="{{::portal.logoutUrl}}">${Logout}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Think you missed the CSS

Comment: need your CSS, to tell you whats the specific problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nk62vok0/ check this it would solve your query.